# Expectation of square root of binomial r.v.

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X\sim B(n,p)$ denote a binomial random variable.  Is there any approximation available for the quantity $E(\sqrt{X})$?  Clearly Jensen's inequality holds, but rudimentary tooling around with Maple hasn't turned up anything more substantial.

Comment: If $np$ is really large, then $X$ is approximately normal. You can take a Taylor series expansion for $\sqrt x$ around the mean of $X$ and get a good approximation for $\mathbb E\sqrt X$. 



Answer (score 20, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbf{E}}$
$\renewcommand{\P}{\mathbf{P}}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{Var}$
If we use Taylor expansion (as Anthony suggested) for $\sqrt{x}$ around 1, we get:
$$\sqrt{x}\approx 1 + \frac{x-1}{2} - \frac{(x-1)^2}{8}  .$$

We can use this to get an approximation of
$$\E(\sqrt{X})\approx 1-\frac{\var(X)}{8} ,$$
which should be valid for any RV concentrated around an expectation of 1. Equivalently,
$$\E(\sqrt{X})\approx \sqrt{\E(X)}\bigg(1-\frac{\var(X)}{8\E(X)^2}\bigg) ,$$
for any RV concentrated around its mean.

As you noted, we can use Jensen inequality to get $\E(\sqrt{X})\le \sqrt{\E(X)}$ for any nonnegative RV. We can tweak the Taylor expansion to get a lower bound, by noticing that
$$ 1 + \frac{x-1}{2} - \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} \le \sqrt{x} \ .$$
Hence, we get
$$\sqrt{\E(X)}\bigg(1-\frac{\var(X)}{2\E(X)^2}\bigg) \le \E(\sqrt{X}) ,$$
for any nonnegative RV.

In the case of $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ we get
$$ \sqrt{np}-\frac{1-p}{2\sqrt{np}} \le \E(\sqrt{X})\le \sqrt{np} .$$

Comment: Can someone help be notice why $1 + \frac{x-1}{2} - \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} \le \sqrt{x} $?

Comment: Sure. Expanding and multiplying by 2 we get that the inequality is equivalent to $3x-x^2 \le 2 \sqrt{x}$. Writing $a=\sqrt{x}$ and dividing we get $3a -a^3 \le 2$ which is true for any $a\ge 0$.

Comment: I don't see how the general inequality $\sqrt{E(X)}\bigg(1-\frac{Var(X)}{2 E(X)^2}\bigg) \le E(\sqrt{X})$ for an arbitrary non-negative RV $X$ follows from $1 + \frac{x-1}{2} - \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} \le \sqrt{x} $. Could you please clarify this point? Is it obvious?

Comment: I can see how it follows from $\sqrt{x} \geq \sqrt{a} +\frac{x-a}{2\sqrt{a}} - \frac{(x-a)^2}{2a^{3/2}}$, which Mathematica tells me is true for all $x \geq 0$ and $a>0$. I suppose there is some simple translation from the inequality you wrote to this more general one? If you consider this too simple or obvious, please don't bother...

Comment: @MarkM.Wilde, You apply the inequality to the RV Y=X/E(X) and take expectation. This is basically equivalent to the inequality you wrote.